# How do I save all the buffers in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I am writing a function in `vimscript` that needs to save all changed, listed buffers that start with current working directory. This operation needs to happen in the background, without changing the current active buffer or a cursor position, if possible.

```
function! SaveChangedBuffers()
    for buf in getbufinfo({'buflisted':1})
        if but.changed && buf.name =~ getcwd() 
           echo buf.name
           "write buf.name <-- how to do this correctly?
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

I wasn't able to find a function in `vimscript` that actually saves the buffer. I know I can supply a filename to `:write` or use a few other options. But I want to make sure I am actually writing all the buffers in a "vim native way" so I don't overwrite or disrupt any other operations or files.

What is the "vim native" way to write a list of buffers to disk from `vimscript`?

Comment: I know this is not what you requested, but will `:wall` work well enough for you? If not I imagine you would have to save the current buffer number, do `:bufdo` to save, and then restore the buffer

Comment: @PeterRincker I have looked at those. `:wall` saves _all_ the files, I want to only limit save operation to the ones that are in the project folder. I kind of randomly open all kinds of files and don't want to accidentally change and write them. `:bufdo` works, but I have to then go back to my original buffer (which is a hassle if you have 150 of them open). Maybe I should just remember my current buffer in the script and then return to it after `:bufdo`...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I was able to achieve my stated goal with the following:

```
function! SaveChangedBuffers()
    set lazyredraw
    let cur_buffer = bufnr('%')
    for buf in getbufinfo({'buflisted':1})
        if buf.changed && buf.name =~ getcwd() 
           execute 'buffer' . buf.bufnr
           update
           " echo buf.name
        endif
    endfor
    execute 'buffer' . cur_buffer
    set nolazyredraw
endfunction
```

`lazyredraw` turns off screen changes while script is running. On slower terminal connections you might not even need that. I then remember the current buffer with `bufnr('%')` and restore it at the end of the script from the variable.

The loop just changes into each buffer that fits the criteria and performs `:update` (which could also be `:write`, because I know my buffer has been changed).

And to complete the full vim experience one can map it to an Ex command (`Wc` stands for "write changed"):

```
command! Wc execute SaveChangedBuffers()
```